# How to prevent end service class to use by controller if it's already used by facade?

Tags: simple-injector

I have a service class and I have used in Facade. I don't want to use service class in controller as it's used in facade using simple injector

Comment: Can you provide example code with your question to show what it is you want to achieve? Your current question is unfortunately too vague.

Comment: Example: There is a class DemoService:IDemoService  and  FacadeDemoService:IFacadeDemoService,IDemoService. I want create ControllerDemoService class and want to inject only IFacadeDemoService not  IDemoService.

Comment: Can you update your question to provide this code in syntactically correct code?

Answer (score 1):

A DI Container is not some magic tool which can help you with such a demand. In that way it is not a Simple Injector or any other DI container related question.

The way I normally prevent anyone from using a specific service in parts of the application where me as an architect have decided they shouldn't be used is by a guarding unittest.

Such a test could look like:

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void IDemoServiceShouldNotBeUsedInAnyService_Use_IFacadeDemoService()
{
    // Arrange
    var typesWithIDemoServiceInConstructor = (
        from assembly in this.GetAssemblies()
        from type in assembly.GetExportedTypes()
        where type != typeof(FacadeDemoService)
        from constructor in type.GetConstructors()
        from constructorParameter in constructor.GetParameters()
        where constructorParameter.ParameterType == IDemoService
        select type).ToArray();

    // Assert
    Assert.IsFalse(typesWithIDemoServiceInConstructor.Any(),
        string.Format("IDemoService should not be used directly! "+
              "Use IFacadeDemoService instead.\r\n" +
              "IDemoService is used in: \r\n{0}",
              string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
                          typesWithIDemoServiceInConstructor.Select(t => t.Name))));
}
```